# How to apply a style generally to all tags, and override this for specific tags

Tags: html, css

I'd like to make all div tags invisible except for the one I mark active in html. Below is an extract from my page:

```
 <div id="container">
   <div id="1">
     invisible
     <div>invisible</div>
     <div>invisible</div>
   </div>
   <div id="2" class="active">
     visible
     <div>visible</div>
     <div>visible</div>
 </div>
```

..or via javascript dom:

document.getElementById("2").classList.add('active');

The expected behavior is that just changing the class will render all "active" classes visible and all unmarked classes invisible at all times.

My first attempt, before adding the parent container and selecting with it,

```
 <style type="text/css">
   div { display:none; }
   div.active { display:block; }
 </style>
```

did not work. It made all divs invisible.

This second attempt, accurately selecting what I really wanted to select, works fine:

```
 <style type="text/css">
   div#container>div.active { display:none; }
   div#container>div { display:block; }
 </style>
```

Is this the right way to override a default style?

Comment: using `div` as a selector is not a good idea .. you will target more than you think, probably a parent container for all your elements

Comment: What you claimed doesn't work, in fact does http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uqbsz0x4/

Comment: I'll me more specific in a repost. hold on.

Comment: @MarkBordelon "repost"? edit this one, don't repost.

Comment: I'm intrigued, How come the example you provided doesn't work ?

Comment: DeDee, that's what I meant with repost (edit the existing). sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:not(selector)` selector. Reference: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Just add to every div `yourChoice` + `active` classes and when you want them to disappear, remove the `yourChoice` class. Then with the `:not(.active) { display: none }` they are all gone.

Here's a codepen https://codepen.io/sebaLinares/pen/EddNbQ

Hope it's useful